# Saving data from Userform to Sheet, get error message: method value of object range failed

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform1 that saves data onto a sheet in the same worksheet, "Input". The userform opens when the worksheet activates, and the excel opens on a separate sheet to "Input".

In the below code, I get the error message: "method value of object range failed" for the following line of code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(lr + 1, "B").Value = cmbGrade
```

`cmbGrade` is a combobox on the userform.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(lr + 1, "B").Value = cmbGrade

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean with "*and the excel opens on a separate sheet to "Input"*" but I worked from scratch, filled the combobox with a few values from sheet2 on initialize of the Userform, clicked the button and got the chosen value in B2 (Input was empty). The only thing I can think of that could be wrong is the sheet name being wrong?

Comment: Hi, apologies, I mean the userform opens with a different sheet being open and activated. "Input" is hidden. The sheet name is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I added a sheet3, changed the "Worksheet_Activate" event to Sheet2, hid "Input" and gave sheet3 a formula to see if my B2 is getting changed. All still works, is `cmdSave_Click` in the Userform1 code-behind?

Comment: Yes. When I run the code, and the error displays, I can see that the "lr" is correctly calculated. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: The lr only confirms your sheetname being correct, not where you have the Private Sub located. If you're not sure what I mean, try putting `Debug.Print Me.Name` in the cmdSave_Click sub (and checking the value given in the Immediate Window, believe that's Ctrl+G to show)

Comment: When I add that into my code it gives me: Me.Name="Userform1"

Comment: Sorry, apart from you not using your sheet variable, there wouldn't be something I'd change nor can I think of something that could be wrong. Somebody told me before to specify more for userform controls, i.e. `Me.cmbGrade` but not even cmbGrade being called different should cause that error..

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway. Just for information, I randomly changed "lr + 1" to "lr" and the formula worked perfectly. Strange!